# python read data like -.345D-4

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am wondering how to read the values like `-.345D+1` with `numpy/scipy`? 
The values are float with first 0 ignored.

I have tried the `numpy.loadtxt` and got errors like

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -.345D+01

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a converter and use the `converters` keyword. If `cols` are the indices of the columns where you expect this format:

```
converters = dict.fromkeys(cols, lambda x: float(x.replace("D", "E")))
np.loadtxt(yourfile, converters=converters)
```